# Capture insert error in Teradata

Tags: loops, error-handling, insert, teradata

I have a stored procedure inserting records into a table in our Teradata data warehouse with the following statement:

```
INSERT INTO UAT_AUDIT_VIEWS.AUDIT_BATCH(
BATCH_KEY
,AUDIT_STATUS_KEY
,BATCH_START_DATETIME
,BATCH_END_DATETIME
,BATCH_OWNER
,BATCH_EXECUTION_START_DATETIME
,BATCH_EXECUTION_END_DATETIME
)
VALUES(
(SELECT COALESCE(MAX(BATCH_KEY),0)+1 FROM UAT_AUDIT_VIEWS.AUDIT_BATCH)
,5 --PENDING
,'1900-01-01 00:00:00'
,'2999-12-31 00:00:00'
,:P_BATCH_OWNER
,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
,'2999-12-31 00:00:00'
);
```

Note that I have a unicity constraint on the primary key BATCH_KEY. In some occasions, my insert statement failed because the primary key already exists in the table. When it happens, I would like my stored procedure to loop and retry the insert until it is successfull.

I have tried multiple solution using the following but was unsuccessful:

- `DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION` to avoid the stored proc to fail when the insert fails
- A `WHILE DO` loop to retry the insert

Could you please describe how you would manage such a scenario?
Here is a simplified version of a test stored procedure I have built to test this (which did not work):

```
REPLACE PROCEDURE DEV_AUDIT_NEW.ARO_TEST_INSERT()
BEGIN
      DECLARE V_BATCH_KEY_CREATED VARCHAR(100);
      DECLARE V_COUNTER SMALLINT DEFAULT 1;
      DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION

      SET V_BATCH_KEY_CREATED = NULL;
      WHILE V_BATCH_KEY_CREATED IS NULL
      DO
            INSERT INTO DEV_AUDIT_NEW.AUDIT_BATCH_TEST_LOG(LOG_DESC) VALUES(V_BATCH_KEY_CREATED);

            INSERT INTO DEV_AUDIT_NEW.AUDIT_BATCH_TEST(BATCH_KEY,BATCH_OWNER) VALUES(V_COUNTER,'B');
            SELECT BATCH_KEY
            INTO :V_BATCH_KEY_CREATED
            FROM DEV_AUDIT_NEW.AUDIT_BATCH_TEST 
            WHERE BATCH_KEY=V_COUNTER AND BATCH_OWNER='B';
            SET V_COUNTER=V_COUNTER+1;

            INSERT INTO DEV_AUDIT_NEW.AUDIT_BATCH_TEST_LOG(LOG_DESC) VALUES(V_BATCH_KEY_CREATED);
      END WHILE;
END;
```

Comment: The key can only exist when you run the SP in parallel. Instead of dealing with concurrency problems you should simply switch to an WRITE lock: `LOCK TABLE UAT_AUDIT_VIEWS.AUDIT_BATCH FOR WRITE INSERT ...`

Comment: I do have multiple teams calling the stored procedure in parallel. We implemented a WRITE LOCK as a first solution but it ended up causing deadlock issues when there was concurrent accesses. This is why I'd like to remove it, capture the insert error and retry. If you have other options I'd be interested?

Comment: The Insert you posted can't cause deadlocks as-is when running in parallel with a WRITE lock on table level. Another solution (which scales better) is based on a sequence table with a single row for this table storing the max value, your SP reads the current value, increases it by one and writes it back.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I still think the WRITE lock was the cause of the deadlock issues because we were able to reproduce the issue and removing it we noticed the issue does not happen anymore (but we have the BATCH_KEY unicity constraint error instead). I don't understand why storing the Max(BATCH_KEY) in a dedicated table would solve any of these 2 issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is too long as a comment.

Your current approach has to do a Full Table Scan to get the MAX (defaults to a read lock on table level), but the Insert defaults to write lock on row hash level. When you request Write on table level it should prevent deadlocks.

When you define a kind of sequence table every access is a UPI-access, e.g.

```
CREATE SET TABLE Sequences
 (
   SequenceName VARCHAR(128) CHARACTER SET Unicode NOT CaseSpecific NOT NULL,
   nextVal BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
 )
UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX ( SequenceName )
;

REPLACE PROCEDURE NextVal (IN SequenceName VARCHAR(128) CHARACTER SET Unicode, OUT NextVal BIGINT)
BEGIN
   BEGIN REQUEST
      LOCK ROW WRITE
      SELECT nextVal INTO :nextVal FROM Sequences 
      WHERE SequenceName = :SequenceName;

      UPDATE Sequences SET nextVal = nextVal + 1 
      WHERE SequenceName = :SequenceName;
   END REQUEST; 
END;
```

Initialize a new sequence:

```
INSERT INTO sequences ('mytable', 1);
```

Get the next value:

```
CALL nextVal('mytable', nextval);`
```

Edit:

You can easily test it using BTEQ logging on multiple sessions in parallel, e.g. to run 1000 CALLs across 10 sessions:

```
.set session 10; 
.logon ...; 
select * from sequences where SequenceName = 'mytable';

.repeat 1000
CALL nextVal('mytable', nextval); 

select * from sequences where SequenceName = 'mytable';
```

Watch the values returning sequentially, no deadlocks :-)

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'm reaching my technical limits here... Do you know what would happen if two processes call the SP NextVal at the same time? Does this implementation guarantees it will not return the same nextVal for these two processes and none of them would face a deadlock? I'll give it a try...

Comment: @Alexis.Rolland: Edited my answer, showed how to test it